# SQL to compare 2 joins to the same table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count, distinct

I have a table that maps accounts to users. Accounts can have multiple users. User can be in multiple accounts.

```
account_id  | user_id 
------------+---------
1234          a
1234          b
5678          c
6789          a
```

For example, here user "a" is in accounts 1234 and 6789.

I have another table with account details.

```
account_id  | status     | ...
------------+------------+-----
1234          ACTIVE
5678          ACTIVE
6789          SUSPENDED
```

I want to know all the users who are ACTIVE in one account while SUSPENDED in another account. (Any mix, if they're in more than 2 accounts.) In the above example, user "a" is ACTIVE in 1234 and SUSPENDED in 6789.

My attempt started as...

```
SELECT user_id FROM mappings
LEFT JOIN account_details AS x ON account_id = x.id AND x.status = 'ACTIVE'
LEFT JOIN account_details AS y ON account_id = y.id AND y.status = 'SUSPENDED'
```

But that seems wrong and I don't know how I'd ensure the 2 joins are linked to the same user. There must be a different way to approach this problem that I'm not seeing.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables to aggregate by user and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.user_id
FROM mappings m INNER JOIN account_details a
ON a.account_id = m.account_id
WHERE a.status IN ('ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED')
GROUP BY m.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.status) = 2;
```

If 'ACTIVE' and 'SUSPENDED' are the only possible values of the column `status` then you can omit the `WHERE` clause.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2753c97ee5ae7204ec1ff3e65da51d04).

Comment: just change `accounts_to_users` with `mappings` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Microsoft SQL Server; it shouldn't be too hard to adapt if you're using a different DBMS:

```
SELECT
    id, ...
FROM
    users As u
WHERE
    Exists
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM mappings As m
        INNER JOIN account_details As a
        ON a.id = m.account_id
        WHERE m.user_id = u.id
        AND a.status = 'ACTIVE'
    )
AND
    Exists
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM mappings As m
        INNER JOIN account_details As a
        ON a.id = m.account_id
        WHERE m.user_id = u.id
        AND a.status = 'SUSPENDED'
    )
;
```